# QR Code Image Generator

Tags: cakephp, qr-code

I'm using QR code generator api from http://goqr.me/api/

Below is the URL used to generate the QR code
https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=Example

When I enter the URL in the browser it returns me an image.
How can I store this image in a folder

I'm using cakephp

I tried this in my code but it doesn't work

```
$file = new File('https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=example');

$file->copy('../webroot/img/user_QR/');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html) to figure simple things like that out.

```
$qrData = file_get_contents('https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=example');
$file = new File('path/to/the-file.jpg', true);
$file->write($qrData);
```

Comment: Thanx... it worked :) I had tried file_get_contents and file_put_contents but didn't work.